# If $B \subset A$ why is $B \in\mathscr P(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone explain why it is true that $B \in\mathscr P(A)$ when $B \subset A$

It should be simple for some but I can't wrap my head around it for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathscr P(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition: $$\mathscr{P}(A) = \{B \mid B \text{ is a subset of }A\}.$$

Then $B \subset A$ is the definition of $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$.